# How to stop for loop in this case?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50], word[50];
    int i;
    char s;

    printf("\nEnter String :");
    fgets(str, 50, stdin);
    printf("\nEnter character: ");
    fgets(word, 50, stdin);
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= strlen(word); j++)
        {
            if (str[i] == word[j])
            {
                s = str[0];
                printf("%c", s);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to input a word and a string, if the word appears in that string, my output will be the first position of the string.
It does print the first position but sometimes it print twice, three times...
Ex:
Input:

```
Enter String :bui ngoc minh chau
Enter word: ngoc
```

Output: `bb`

Comment: You copy and print `s[0]` instead of `s[i]` or `word[j]` in the body of the innermost `if`.  You could avoid the variable `s` and simply print one or the other indexed expression.  You could also make your `for` loops consistent with each — both should use the `for (int var = 0; var < limit; var++)` notation.  You probably don't wnt the `<=` condition but rather use `<`.  That will avoid processing null bytes.    It might be better to use `sizeof(str)` instead of `50` in the call to `fgets()`.

Comment: "if the word appears in that string" Your algorithm doesn't do anything like that. Try testing with the string "abc" and the word "cba".

Answer (score 1):

there are some error in your code:

1. the inner `for` loop should be for `(int j = 0;j < strlen(word); j++)`
2. if you want the first position the word in the string, you can do this:

   ```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<string.h>
   #include<stdbool.h>

   int main()
   {
       char str[50], word[50];
       printf("Enter String: ");
       fgets(str, 50, stdin);
       printf("Enter Word: ");
       fgets(word, 50, stdin);

       int str_len = strlen(str);
       int word_len = strlen(word);

       bool found = false;

       for (int i = 0; i <= str_len - word_len; i++)
       {
           int j;
           for (j = 0; j < word_len; j++)
           {
               if (str[i + j] != word[j])
                   break;
           }
           if (j == word_len)
           {
               printf("Word found at index: %d\n", i);
               found = true;
               break;
           }
       }

       if (!found)
           printf("Word not found in the string.\n");

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: "str_len - word_len" I dont understand what does it means? Could you explain it for me? Thankyou

Comment: i is represent the first index that word appear in str_len. so i + word_len-1 <= str_len-1 
<=> i<= str_len - word_len.
let explain by example.
enter string : abcdefgh
word: xyz
you will compare sequentially 
'xyz' vs 'abc'
'xyz' vs 'bcd'
...
'xyz' vs 'fgh'
in last case , i = position of character f = 5 =8-3.
if i > str_len - word_len, i = 6, i =7
you will receive xyz vs 'gh', xyz vs 'h'. Easy to see that can't fine word  because when i > str_len - word_len, the max length you can get from str is alway < word_len.
p/s: sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what your goal is: if you mean to print the first character of the string in `str` if the word in `word` in the string in `str`, you should strip the trailing newline and use `strstr()`. Your code does not do that, it prints the character in `str` for each occurrence of the first character in `word`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50], word[50];

    printf("Enter String: ");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    printf("Enter Word: ");
    if (!fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin))
        return 1;

    size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    size_t word_len = strlen(word);

    if (word_len > 0 && word[word_len - 1] == '\n')
        word[--word_len] == '\0'

    if (strstr(str, word) != NULL) 
        printf("%c\n", str[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to perform the search manually, you still need to stop at the newline and iterate in the inner loop until the null byte or the newline, whatever comes first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50], word[50];
    bool found = false;

    printf("Enter String: ");
    if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
        return 1;

    printf("Enter Word: ");
    if (!fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin))
        return 1;

    if (word[0] == '\0' || word[0] == '\n') {
        printf("word is empty\n");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; str[i] == '\0' || str[i] == '\n'; i++) {
            found = true;
            for (int j = 0; word[j] == '\0' && word[j] == '\n'; j++) {
                if (str[i + j] != word[j]) {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (found)
                break;
        }
        if (found)
            printf("%c\n", str[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```